# Prevent user from changing any account data once it is setup

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Is there a means of preventing Woocommerce customers from changing any of their billing/shipping info once it is setup?

Comment: It might be useful to explain why that is needed.  For instance: It would seem that allowing the customer to change their shipping address is a 'good thing'. What if the customer moves? Do they have to create a brand new customer record with their new address?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the customer account page shows `Edit` links with the customer **Billing** and **Shipping addresses**.

You could override this template to remove it, but you can easily remove HTML elements via **jQuery** as well. As both of these edit links have the CSS class `.edit`, you can target both with one statement. Use the following code on your `functions.php`.

```
// Remove "Edit" links from My Account > Addresses
function sv_remove_edit_account_links() {
    wc_enqueue_js( "
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery( 'a.edit' ).remove();
        });
    " );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_my_account', 'sv_remove_edit_account_links' );
```

---

### Change Account Welcome

The account `Welcome message` also mention editing account stuff. You can easily filter to translate this text. You'll change this text to remove the mention of managing shipping and billing addresses. Use the following code on your `functions.php`.

```
// Change the "My Account" welcome text
function sv_change_wc_account_welcome( $translated_text, $original_text, $domain ) {

    // bail if we're in the admin or not using a WooCommerce string
    if ( is_admin() || 'woocommerce' !== $domain ) {
        return $translated_text;
    }

    $text = 'From your account dashboard you can view your recent orders, manage your shipping and billing addresses and <a href="%s">edit your password and account details</a>.';

    if ( $text === $original_text ) {
        $translated_text = 'From your account dashboard, you can view your recent orders, shipping and billing addresses, and <a href="%s">edit your password and account details</a>.';
    }

    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'sv_change_wc_account_welcome', 10, 3 );
```

Now once you've put these two snippets together, our account welcome message will be changed, and the `Edit` links will be removed for both customer addresses. This leaves the customer with the ability to edit the core account details like name, but not the addresses.